# Python 3 Web Scraping 403 Error Forbidden With Header Request

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

So, i was practicing my web scraping skill. I was able to do some of the website that is open (ex: .org, etc.)

But I try some of the other website, but I kept getting return of 403 Forbidden Error. Does it think I am bot?

Here is the script:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import random

url = "https://www.realestate.com.au/property/30-colane-st-concord-west-nsw-2138"

tables = pd.read_html(url)

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

tables = soup.find_all('table', 'table')

df1 = pd.read_html(str(tables[0]))
df1 = df1[0]
print(df1)

df2 = pd.read_html(str(tables[0]))
df2 = df2[0]
print(df2)
```

I was trying to make the status code is 200, like what i did in here but what i did get just too many request

```py
import requests

my_session = requests.session()
for_cookies = my_session.get("https://www.realestate.com.au")
cookies = for_cookies.cookies
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
my_url = 'https://www.realestate.com.au/property/30-colane-st-concord-west-nsw-2138'

response = my_session.get(my_url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
print(response.status_code)  # 200
```